# Ios swift replace selector by function

Tags: ios, uibutton, swift2, action, selector

I just want to write one or two lines of code on button click like

```
print("Button Clicked")
```

for this i dont want to create a seperate function and call via selector
as

```
action: #selector(BtnKlkFnc(_:))
```

I want to simplify like

```
action: { action in print("Button Clicked")}
```

I also tried

```
#selector({print("Button Clicked")})
```

Can anyone help me to simplify this

Am new to stackoverflow and do not have enough reputations yet, So kindly vote for my question up, so i can vote for your ans

Comment: you cannot simplify this. What you want is not possible, use a function.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37903243/1630618

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: You can't do that. Button actions are part of the target/action mechanism built into Cocoa/Cocoa touch. It's based on selectors, and you must create a named method and use it's selector. You can't use a Swift closure as a button action.

### EDIT:

Note that it is possible to create a custom subclass of UIButton that has a closure property and invokes that closure when the button is tapped. What you'd do is to make the button's init method set itself up as the target of a touchUpInside event and invoke a method of the button that in turn invokes your closure (after making sure the closure property isn't nil.)

### EDIT #2:

Note that it is pretty straightforward to create a custom subclass of `UIButton` that sets itself up as the target for button presses and keeps a closure.

Here is a sample implementation:

```
class ClosureButton: UIButton {

    var buttonClosure: ((UIButton) -> Void)?
    
     required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleTap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        }
    
    @objc func handleTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let buttonClosure = buttonClosure {
            buttonClosure(sender)
        } else {
            print("No button closure defined")
            return
        }
    }
}
```

And in your view controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    button.buttonClosure = { _ in
        print("You tapped the button")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.
Am new to stackoverflow and do not have enough reputations yet, So kindly vote for my question up, so i can vote for your ans

Comment: @SujayUN, I updated my answer with a custom version of UIButton that does what you want.