# store #selector in a variable

Tags: ios, swift

I'm adding a target to a button but instead of having the target action reference a predefined function I want it to reference a closure.

```
typealias AlertAction = (title: String, handler: () -> ())

class ErrorView: UIView {

  func addAction(_ action: AlertAction) {
    let button = UIButton()
    ...
    let selector = #selector(action.handler) //error happens here
    button.addTarget(self, action: selector, for: .touchUpInside)
  }
}
```

I'm getting an error on this line:

```
let selector = #selector(action.handler)
```

which is "Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an '@objc' method, property, or initializer"

This makes sense because usually you have to add @objc to your func declaration, but I'm wondering if there's a way to make my closure refer to an @objc method after the fact perhaps by wrapping it in another function.

Is this possible? I don't know how to define an @objc marked closure so I'm not sure.

Comment: There's no easy way to bridge between the world of Swift closures, and the world of ObjectiveC targets/selectors. The best you can do is try to write some code that uses the ObjectiveC runtime to make a function that takes a closure (which will be limited to being `@convention(c)`), adds it as a method to a fake class, and gives you a selector that you can then use to reference that method. It'd be pretty tricky, though.

Comment: Take a look at [what I did here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37903243/1630618).

Answer (score 0):

`#selector()` is based on Objective-C bridging, since swift closures are non-objective-c, you can't use them.

One alternative solution is wrap your code inside an Objective-C function.

```
class AlertAction:NSObject {
    var title:String?

    @objc
    func getHandler(sender:Any){
        print("hi")
    }
}
```

and use it like:

```
// Instance of a class
let alertAction = AlertAction()

// Usage
let button = UIButton()
let selector1 = #selector(AlertAction.getHandler)
button.addTarget(alertAction, action: selector1, for: .touchUpInside)
```